# Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/cloudenv] not found

Tags: jndi

I am getting below error message when I deploy application into Tomcat 7.

> 2016-02-11 11:52:30,200 DEBUG (localhost-startStop-1) [org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/cloudenv] not found - trying original name [cloudenv]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [cloudenv] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [cloudenv].

I would like to know from where "cloudenv" is mention in the application. I could not find such string my application. I also could not find "java:comp/env/" string in my application. Please me know what am I missing to understand the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question!!! It is due to that I am using dynamic variable in application context. It is trying to search from 5 areas:-

```
[servletConfigInitParams]
[servletContextInitParams]
[jndiProperties]
[systemProperties]
[systemEnvironment]
```

For jndi, the default search variable is "java:comp/env/" + ${dynamic variable}